# how to apply style on dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function createList(arrunique, arrayout) {
    for (i = 0; i < arrayout[0].length; i++) {
        var divIdC = i;
        var divIdT = i + 10;

        $('#tb').append('<select name="combo" style="float:left; width:100px;" id="' + divIdC + '" onchange="getComboVal(this,' + divIdC + ')"></select>');
        $('#tb').append('<input type="text" name = "textBox" style= "width:100px;" id="' + divIdT + '" onkeyup="validate(this,"' + divIdT + '") value="0">');
        var select = document.getElementById(divIdC);
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("Select " + arrunique[i][0]);
        for (j = 1; j < arrunique[i].length; j++) {
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(arrunique[i][j]);
        };
    };
}
```

In this code I want to generate a combo box and a textbox and I want to apply some style sheet attribute or any class. How can I do this. Its not working.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's happening? "Not working" doesn't describe the problem – are your elements appearing unstyled, are you getting error messages in the console, etc.

Comment: Seems to be [working fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/4CQfg/).  What's the console output saying?

Comment: @Nav Kumar on which event you are calling this function. createList... :)

Comment: Using 'select' as a variable name is not a very good coding practice. And please provide more details as requested by Scottie.

Comment: no i have div with width 200 px in this div i want both combo box and text box display on a single row  but its appear in a up down so i want on a row and the style tag is not working so how can it works

Comment: console saying nothing but like width or any style colore backround not working

Comment: It can be called immediately: see [updated JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CQfg/3/)

Comment: i have a fuction to convert csv to table and these are the headers of this file so i want these header ina combo box and this creatlist is called inside that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#tb').append('<input type="text" class="YOURCLASS" name = "textBox" style= "width:100px;" id="'+divIdT+'" onkeyup="validate(this,"'+divIdT+'") value="0">');
```

Comment: -3 without any explanation?

Comment: Yeah your right. they didn't give any explanation. but then again.... neither did you.

Comment: Adding to what @Pinocchio said - this sort of code can get real messy real fast.

Comment: Poor styling (no whitespace between attribute and value), inline styles, inline JS, string concatenation leading to XSS vectors, and `YOUCLASS` just looks silly.

Answer (score 11):

There are many, many ways of styling a javascript created element. Here are a few.
[Click here for live demo.](http://jsbin.com/OLubuNA/1/edit)

```
var myElem = document.createElement('div');
myElem.style.color = '#FFF';
```

with jQuery:

```
var $myElem = $('<div></div>');
$myElem.css('color', '#FFF');
```

or jQuery css object syntax (for passing multiple styles)

```
$myElem.css({display: 'block', background: '#000'});
```

Rather than adding the style after creating the element, you may also consider just adding a class to the element after creating it and styling this class in your css file.

CSS file:

```
.myElem {
  color: #FFF;
}


myElem.className = 'myElem';
```

or

```
$myElem.addClass('myElem');
```

Answer (score 0):

See this simplified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CQfg/4/).  Ensure that the console is not generating an errors, and that you're calling the `createList()` function.